# Using values outside of overridden method leads to null

Tags: java, android, interface

In my Post class, within saveBitmap method, I'm using the method from my interface to go to a URL and retrieve the image into a bitmap then return it. It works fine, it does retrieve the bitmap but if I try to use bitmap[0] outside of the interface method (in Figure 1) it says it's null.

So whenever I have to work on the retrieved value, it must be inside the method and it won't let me take it out for some reason. The other problem that follows this (which I think could be tied) is that I need to override the method onDownloadComplete twice. At the very bottom of my Post class, you can see it's overridden again with an empty body. I have that just so the very top line of my Post class, where I implement onDownloadImageListener, doesn't red-line.

I'm not sure how to fix this, I would like to be able to retrieve the values outside of the the listener method.

**Post class:**

```
public class Post extends Fragment implements OnDownloadImageListener {
...
private void saveBitmap(String userName, String key){
    DownloadImage downloadImage = new DownloadImage();
    final Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[1];
    final String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + key + "/picture?type=large";

    downloadImage.execute(url);
    downloadImage.setOnDownloadImageListener(new OnDownloadImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadComplete(Bitmap bmap) {
            bitmap[0] = bmap;
        }
    });
    //**FIGURE 1**
}

@Override
public void onDownloadComplete(Bitmap bmap) { //I need this otherwise it gives me an error on the top line where I have "implements OnDownloadImageListener"
```

**DownloadImage class:**

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private OnDownloadImageListener listener;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

    String imageURL = URL[0];

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        // Download Image from URL
        InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
        // Decode Bitmap
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if(listener!=null){
        listener.onDownloadComplete(result);
    }
}

public void setOnDownloadImageListener(OnDownloadImageListener listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}
}
```

and finally, **My interface/listener:**

```
public interface OnDownloadImageListener {
     void onDownloadComplete(Bitmap bmap);
}
```

Comment: Use `downloadImage.setOnDownloadImageListener(this)` and process the `Bitmap` passed in the `onDownloadComplete(Bitmap bmap)` method _"At the very bottom of my Post class"_.

Comment: @Onik thank you, that solved part of my problem of using two of the same methods. but if I use a global variable to set as the value being retrieved from onDownloadComplete, it still returns null for some reason unless it's being used inside of onDownloadComplete. any particular solution for this?

Comment: _"it still returns null for some reason unless it's being used inside of onDownloadComplete. any particular solution for this?"_ Of course not! Getting a network response in your case is an asynchronous operation. The `Bitmap`'s value will be untouched until the operation is done. Till then the `Bitmap` equals to its initial value (so if it's `null` it's `null`). That's why you use an interface - to inform the `Post` class that `Bitmap`'s value has changed.

Comment: I recommend using a framework for this task, such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki)

Comment: @Onik ah right, i almost forgot i'm using async task so that'll give me hell. thank you again for your help.

Comment: @weston see, I would love to use Glide or Picasso but I have trouble getting context in my fragments for some reason it's not working when i use getActivity

Comment: @weston or for example, overriding fragment methods like onViewCreated or onActivityCreated, setting context variables inside that then using them in glide never worked for me exactly.

Comment: I suggest you ask a question about those problems then.

Comment: @weston DONE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in this (referring to the class Post that implements the interface OnDownloadImageListener) into the setOnDownloadImageListener method of the DownloadImage object downloadImage.

```
public class Post extends Fragment implements OnDownloadImageListener {
...
private void saveBitmap(String userName, String key){
    DownloadImage downloadImage = new DownloadImage();
    final Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[1];
    final String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + key + "/picture?  type=large";

    downloadImage.execute(url);
    downloadImage.setOnDownloadImageListener(this);
    //**FIGURE 1**
}

@Override
public void onDownloadComplete(Bitmap bmap) { 
    bitmap[0] = bmap; //fixed the variable error
}
```